# Wrong code color profile applied when file is opened

Tags: visual-studio-code

This problem started to occur about two days ago, when I open a file in VS Code the right color profile is applied but then after a split second it changes to something else. It does not matter which theme I am using, nor which extension I disable or enable.

Not sure what I did for this to happen. The only thing I can think of is upgrading Node to the latest version. How do I stop this from happening?

**settings.json**

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Cobalt Next",
    "breadcrumbs.enabled": false,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false
}
```

**Problem**

[image: Example of the problem]

Comment: It's definitely not nodeJS, it wouldn't affect the code in editor (effectively presentation layer) like that. To me it looks like a linting thing, or perhaps you've got conflicting language definitions somewhere?

Comment: Allegedly there's a new feature in the latest version called "semantic highlighting", turn it off in your settings.

Comment: You are absolutely right my friend. It was a [new feature](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview). Will be disabled by default in the next release (1.43.1). If you pop it into an answer I'll accept it. It can be disabled using this setting: `"editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false`.